# Abstracts in rmarkdown that include numbers generated from the rmd itself?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, knitr

So basically I have been writing a paper in Rmarkdown. The paper includes an abstract which has numbers/results that are generated from the code chunks within the markdown itself. Up to now, the workaround has been to place the abstract at the end of the paper, so that all the code chunks are run and the results generated before they are needed in the abstract.

Now that I am actually working on the final drafts, It would be ideal to have the abstract in the beginning. Is this even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a rather vague question, and doesn't really seem suited for SO. But, maybe you could have all of the code chunks at the top of the document, name them, and then call them as needed throughout the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your values won't change from run to run, one option is to use `knitr::load_cache` to load values from the cache of later chunks in your abstract section. The main downside is that this will only work on the **second** time knitting the document. The first time, load_cache will give NULL, then the later chunk will be run and the value cached. The second time, the cache will exist and will be used in the abstract.

````
```{r abstract}
y = knitr::load_cache('test-a', 'y')
print(y)
```

```{r test-a, cache=TRUE}
y = 2*pi
```
````

The first time you run it will give you this:

[image]

But knit it again and you'll see this:

[image]

This is kind of awkward, but was the recommended solution from yihui, the creator of rmarkdown. See this github issue: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/868#issuecomment-68129294

You have to be careful with cached chunks – make sure that there is nothing that would change between runs and clear the cache before doing your final (2-step) knitting.